# Grails - MongoDB and custom dirty checking

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-domain-class

I am using MongoDB and Spring Security Core and UI on my application. 
Nearly everything works perfectly, except this bit:

```
    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }
```

which is part of the User domain class. I have read that dirty checking was not supported by the MongoDB plugin yet. So I tried to implement my own like this:

```
if ( User.collection.findOne(id:id).password != password ) {
            encodePassword()
        }
```

But it is not working. I get the classical `Cannot get property 'password' on null object.`

Does anyone know how to reference an instance from the domain class definition ? 
I am also open to any better idea to implement the dirty checking.

Comment: See last comment at this JIRA issue: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-114?focusedCommentId=69898&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-69898 "You'll need to delete the beforeInsert, beforeUpdate, and encodePassword methods and encrypt the password like in earlier versions of the plugin, using springSecurityService.encodePassword() in controllers, services, etc."

Answer (score 2):

Maybe findOne is returning null? Did you try:

```
def existing = User.collection.findOne(id:id)?.password 
if ( !existing || existing != password )
```

Comment: This works.  I did User.collection?.findOne(id)?.password, in case we are running a unit test and collection is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same problem, until the dynamic methods work, this will have to do:

```
def mongo
def beforeUpdate() {
    def persisted = mongo.getDB("test").user.findOne(id).password
    def encodedNew = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    if(persisted != encodedNew) password = encodedNew
    //if (isDirty('password')) {
    //  encodePassword()
    //}
}
```

Comment: You should be comparing against the un-encoded password I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.collection.findOne(_id:id).password
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue as well - here is my solution:

```
def beforeUpdate() {
    User.withNewSession {
        def user = User.findByUsername(this.username)
        if ( !user?.password || user?.password != password) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is a more efficient way.